# Using PyMC to perform double integration

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, pymc, mcmc

I need to perform double integration using [MCMC method](http://en.mobile.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo#section_1). I have already done it using [romberg](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.romberg.html) and [doublequad](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html) integrations with correct results. I need to also use MCMC integration to compare the results. I found it difficult to understand [PyMC](http://pymc.googlecode.com/svn/doc/index.html).

The outline is this: I have some timeseries data and I need to find out which distribution fits it. I have a set of equations that tells me what to do that involves Double Integration.

Hoping for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you start with a simple direct sampling MC and do a trivial 2D integral for which you can obtain the answer by paper and pencil. Then move on to a MCMC for the same integral.